# markdown / html: keep indent for second line after colon

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, auto-indent

The task is to put text in colored blocks (background-color, padding, round corner, border-line, etc.). Within the block, on Example 2 Explanation, the second line should automatically keep the indents and align after the colon on the first line. The output I want is shown in the image below if my explanation isn't clear enough.

I'm writing in **Jupiter notebook**. Markdown syntax and html can be recognized. I'm not sure how to make css work?

I've seen some questions here very related but their answer doesn't work for me. Such as: How to keep indent for second line in ordered lists via CSS?

[image]

### My attempt

The best I can do is shown below, however it has problems.

1. I used `<pre>` tag which indents the entire block but I don't know how to remove. (No one on the internet seems to have this problem and I start to wonder if it's because I code on Jupiter notebook??)
2. the second line of **Explanation** in `Example 2` doesn't align after the colon on the first line.

This is an old problem and I pretty much gave up after several hours' attempt. Sorry for the late update.

[image]

```
<p><strong>Example 1:</strong></p>
<pre style="background-color:#F5F5F5; padding:10px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius:5px;">
<strong>Input:</strong> "42"
<strong>Output:</strong> 42
</pre>

<p><strong>Example 2:</strong></p>
<pre style="background-color:#F5F5F5; padding:10px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius:5px;">
<strong>Input:</strong> "   -42"
<strong>Output:</strong> -42
<strong>Explanation:</strong> The first non-whitespace character is '-', which is the minus sign. Then take as many numerical digits as possible, which gets 42.
</pre>
```

Comment: Please provide some code showing what you have tried. At a minimum, the HTML you want to style (the Markdown which renders to HTML might work, but the HTML is much more useful). A screenshot might relay what you want, but without knowing the structure of you source document, it's difficult to provide any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `div` tag in markdown `inlinehtml`.

```
<div style="clear: both; display: table">
<div style="float: 100px; width: 100px; ">
<strong>Explanation: </strong>
</div> 
<div style="float: left; width: 500px;">
The first non-whitespace character is '-', which is the minus sign. Then take as many numerical digits as possible, which gets 42. 
</div>
</div>
```

You might use `definition list` in html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: auto;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold
}
dt::after {
  content: ":";
}
dd {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>A dd element is displayed like this:</p>

<dl>
  <dt>Input</dt> 
  <dd> 42 </dd>

  <dt>Output</dt> 
  <dd> 42 </dd>

  <dt>Explanation</dt>
  <dd>The first non-whitespace character is '-', which is the minus sign. Then take as many numerical digits as possible, which gets 42.</dd>
</dl>

<p>Change the default CSS settings to see the effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was nicely put, but it seems that <style> tags doesn't work in Markdown.. qwq